# Does Mysql support PMML

Tags: mysql, database, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pmml

I couldn't find any reference that MySQL DB supports PMML using a search engine. I was wondering if anyone had any luck with this. I would like to deploy a Random Forest model that is built in Sklearn in MySQL (I'm aware of other workarounds - but want to get an answer to this question before I go down the other route).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PMML is a ML domain-specific language, and is hardly relevant for most database engines/applications. Your best option is to find a 3rd party PMML engine, and integrate it with SQL engine over some bridge technology, such as user-defined functions (UDFs).

If you're looking to deploy Scikit-Learn models on MySQL, then the [sklearn2sql](https://github.com/antoinecarme/sklearn2sql-demo) project might be helpful. Previously, there was a [pmml2sql](http://pmml2sql.com/) project, which aimed to provide greater flexibility, but it appears to be discontinued now. Of course, Random Forest models can be quite large, which may make the translation to SQL a bit problematic.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a fellow answer, chances are slim you'll be able to evaluate PMML directy in the database in the foreseeable future. You can, however, convert your model to SQL using the [SKompiler](https://github.com/konstantint/SKompiler) library:

```
from skompiler import skompile
skompile(rf.predict_proba).to('sqlalchemy/mysql')
```